# React native soloader

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-navigation-drawer, react-native-hermes

Error: Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libreanimated.so
SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.my/lib-main flags = 1]
SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~NGqmBYqJ1S0FmaG7gXQb4g==/com.my-HJS7umVyDKZb0i1fDJQ9Bw==/lib/x86_64 flags = 0]
SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
react-native-reanimated 3.3.0
react-native 0.71.11

Comment: I fix it npm uninstall react-native-reanimated
npm install react-native-reanimated@2.2.4
npx react-native start --reset-cache